# gnuplot: fill area curve keeping tics on top

Tags: gnuplot, fill, area, axis-labels

in gnuplot, when you try to fill an area under a curve, the tics of both axes are hinded behind the solid area.
Is there any way to give them to the front?
I am using postcript terminal, where no transparent features are allowed (i guess)
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

There sure is!  Before plotting, run this interactively or in a script:

```
set tics front
```

Try `help tics` interactively for more info.

Answer (score 1):

After trying many options I realized that the following works properly:

```
set tics front
```

It seems important to write it before the plot command.

;-)